# calculating OHLC data in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file:

```
_id,ltp,volume,time
5f4dde2e9f742701e3d9a15c,214.55,29077675,2020-09-01T11:07:50.000Z
5f4dde2f9f742701e3d9a15d,214.55,29077690,2020-09-01T11:07:50.000Z
5f4dde2f9f742701e3d9a15e,214.65,29077690,2020-09-01T11:07:51.000Z
5f4dde309f742701e3d9a15f,214.65,29077900,2020-09-01T11:07:51.000Z
5f4dde309f742701e3d9a160,214.6,29077900,2020-09-01T11:07:52.000Z
5f4dde319f742701e3d9a161,214.7,29078191,2020-09-01T11:07:53.000Z
5f4dde329f742701e3d9a162,214.6,29078769,2020-09-01T11:07:54.000Z
5f4dde339f742701e3d9a163,214.65,29078832,2020-09-01T11:07:55.000Z
```

I need to calculate the `OHLC` from this data for a given interval. `open` is the first element in the interval, `high` is max, `low` is min, `close` is last.

This is achieved by following code similar to this:

```
data = df.resample('1T').agg({'ltp': ['first', 'max', 'min', 'last'], 'volume': 'sum'})
```

problem 1: I can't get open, high, low, close column separate with the above code it is inside 'ltp' column. In order to access `open` I need to write `data['ltp']['first']`. (But this is a minor issue can be ignored)

problem 2: Main problem is when calculating `volume` currently I have `sum` but actually what I want to achieve is this, for example `volume` at `10:01:00` is `100` and at `10:02:00` is `200` so total volume for that time frame is `200-100 = 100`, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem you just have to rename the columns or drop one level. For your second problem, take first and last and calculate the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["5f4dde2e9f742701e3d9a15c",214.55,29077675,"2020-09-01T11:07:50.000Z"],
["5f4dde2f9f742701e3d9a15d",214.55,29077690,"2020-09-01T11:07:50.000Z"],
["5f4dde2f9f742701e3d9a15e",214.65,29077690,"2020-09-01T11:07:51.000Z"],
["5f4dde309f742701e3d9a15f",214.65,29077900,"2020-09-01T11:07:51.000Z"],
["5f4dde309f742701e3d9a160",214.6,29077900,"2020-09-01T11:07:52.000Z"],
["5f4dde319f742701e3d9a161",214.7,29078191,"2020-09-01T11:07:53.000Z"],
["5f4dde329f742701e3d9a162",214.6,29078769,"2020-09-01T11:07:54.000Z"],
["5f4dde339f742701e3d9a163",214.65,29078832,"2020-09-01T11:07:55.000Z"]], columns = ["_id","ltp","volume","time"])

df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df = df.set_index("time")
data = df.resample('1S').agg({'ltp': ['first', 'max', 'min', 'last'], 'volume': ['first','last']})

data.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in data.columns.ravel()]
data["volumne_metric"] = data["volume_last"]-data["volume_first"]
```

Output:

```
                         ltp_first  ltp_max ltp_min ltp_last volume_first volume_last volumne_metric
time                            
2020-09-01 11:07:50+00:00   214.55  214.55  214.55  214.55  29077675    29077690    15
2020-09-01 11:07:51+00:00   214.65  214.65  214.65  214.65  29077690    29077900    210
2020-09-01 11:07:52+00:00   214.60  214.60  214.60  214.60  29077900    29077900    0
2020-09-01 11:07:53+00:00   214.70  214.70  214.70  214.70  29078191    29078191    0
2020-09-01 11:07:54+00:00   214.60  214.60  214.60  214.60  29078769    29078769    0
2020-09-01 11:07:55+00:00   214.65  214.65  214.65  214.65  29078832    29078832    0
```